# Passing username to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-props

I have 3 components: SearchUsers, UserInfoCard and RepoCard. In SearchUsers, I get user info from Github API, with entering a username. And In RepoCard I want to show public repos of a spesific user. So, to do that, I need to pass this username state to RepoCard. But everytime I enter a username, https://api.github.com/users/undefined/repos I get this. Here is my RepoCard component.`

```
const RepoCard = ({ username }) => {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  const [repoDetails, setRepoDetails] = useState();
  const [repoDetailsLoading, setRepoDetailsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick(!click);
    console.log(click);
  };

  function searchRepos() {
    // setLoading(true);
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`).then((res) => {
      //   setLoading(false);
      setRepoDetails(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
      console.log(username);
    });
  }

  function renderRepo(repo) {
    return (
      <div
        className={styles.repoContainer}
        onClick={() => getRepoDetails(repo.name)}
        key={repo.id}
      >
        <h2 className={styles.repoName}>{repo.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function getRepoDetails(repoName) {
    setRepoDetailsLoading(true);
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoName}`).then(
      (res) => {
        setRepoDetailsLoading(false);
        setRepoDetails(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.resultsContainer}>
      {repos.map(renderRepo)}
      <button className={styles.listRepos} onClick={searchRepos}>
        List public repos:
      </button>
      {repoDetails}

      <div className={styles.repoInfo}>
        <div className={styles.starRepo}>
          <div
            className={
              click ? `${styles.icon} ${styles.active}` : `${styles.icon}`
            }
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            <FaStar />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.repoDetail}>
          <label className={styles.repoLabel}>Repo Name</label>
          <span className={styles.value}>
            {" "}
            <a target="_blank" href={repoDetails?.svn_url}>
              {repoDetails?.name} <FaExternalLinkAlt />
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <div className={styles.repoDetail}>
          <label className={styles.repoLabel}>Created at</label>
          <span className={styles.value}>{repoDetails?.created_at}</span>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>

        <div className={styles.repoDetail}>
          <label className={styles.repoLabel}>Language</label>
          <span className={styles.value}> {repoDetails?.language}</span>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RepoCard;
```

SearchUser component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { FaStar, FaExternalLinkAlt } from "react-icons/fa";

import { api } from "../../services/api";
import styles from "./index.module.css";

import UserInfoCard from "../UserInfoCard";
import RepoCard from "../RepoCard";

const SearchUser = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  // const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  // const [repoDetails, setRepoDetails] = useState();
  // const [repoDetailsLoading, setRepoDetailsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});
  const [userDetailsLoading, setUserDetailsLoading] = useState(false);

 

  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick(!click);
    console.log(click);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers([]);
    setUserDetails({});
    // setRepoDetails();
  }, [username]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchUsers();
  }

  // function searchRepos() {
  //   fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`)
  //     .then((res) => res.json())
  //     .then(
  //       (result) => {
  //         console.log(result);

  //         const list = result.map((item) => (
  //           <div className={styles.repoInfo}>
  //             <div className={styles.starRepo}>
  //               <div
  //                 className={
  //                   click ? `${styles.icon} ${styles.active}` : `${styles.icon}`
  //                 }
  //                 onClick={handleClick}
  //               >
  //                 <FaStar />
  //               </div>
  //             </div>

  //             <div className={styles.repoDetail}>
  //               <label className={styles.repoLabel}>Repo Name</label>
  //               <span className={styles.value}>
  //                 {" "}
  //                 <a target="_blank" href={item.svn_url}>
  //                   {item.name} <FaExternalLinkAlt />
  //                 </a>
  //               </span>
  //             </div>
  //             <hr></hr>
  //             <div className={styles.repoDetail}>
  //               <label className={styles.repoLabel}>Created at</label>
  //               <span className={styles.value}>{item?.created_at}</span>
  //             </div>
  //             <hr></hr>

  //             <div className={styles.repoDetail}>
  //               <label className={styles.repoLabel}>Language</label>
  //               <span className={styles.value}> {item?.language}</span>
  //             </div>
  //             <hr></hr>
  //           </div>
  //         ));
  //         setRepoDetails(list);
  //       },
  //       (error) => {
  //         console.log(error);
  //       }
  //     );
  // }

  // function renderRepo(repo) {
  //   return (
  //     <div
  //       className={styles.repoContainer}
  //       onClick={() => getRepoDetails(repo.name)}
  //       key={repo.id}
  //     >
  //       <h2 className={styles.repoName}>{repo.name}</h2>
  //     </div>
  //   );
  // }

  // function getRepoDetails(repoName) {
  //   setRepoDetailsLoading(true);
  //   fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoName}`).then(
  //     (res) => {
  //       setRepoDetailsLoading(false);
  //       setRepoDetails(res.data);
  //     }
  //   );
  // }

  function searchUsers() {
    setLoading(true);
    api.get(`/users/${username}`).then((res) => {
      setLoading(false);
      setUserDetails(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  }

  function renderUser(user) {
    return (
      <div
        className={styles.userInfoContainer}
        onClick={() => getUserDetails(user.name)}
        key={user.id}
      >
        <h2 className={styles.username}>{user.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function getUserDetails(username) {
    setUserDetailsLoading(true);
    api.get(`/users/${username}`).then((res) => {
      setUserDetailsLoading(false);
      setUserDetails(res.data);
    });
  }

  // async function repoDataURL() {
  //   //Get repo data about github user
  //   await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`)
  //     .then((res) => res.json())
  //     .then(
  //       (result) => {
  //         console.log(36, result);
  //         const list = result.map((item) => (
  //           <div className="text-center">
  //             <a target="_blank" href={item.svn_url}>
  //               {item.name}
  //             </a>
  //           </div>
  //         ));
  //         setRepoDetails(list);
  //       },
  //       (error) => {
  //         console.log(error);
  //       }
  //     );
  // }

  return (
    <div className={styles.searchContainer}>
      <form className={styles.form}>
        <input
          className={styles.input}
          value={username}
          placeholder="Bir kullanıcı adı giriniz"
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button className={styles.searchButton} onClick={handleSubmit}>
          {loading ? "Searching..." : "Search"}
        </button>
      </form>

      <div className={styles.resultsContainer}>{users.map(renderUser)}</div>
      <UserInfoCard
        userDetails={userDetails}
        userDetailsLoading={userDetailsLoading}
        // searchRepos={searchRepos}
        // repoDetails={repoDetails}
        // renderRepo={renderRepo}
        // repos={repos}
      />

      {/* <div className={styles.resultsContainer}>{repos.map(renderRepo)}</div>

      <button className={styles.listRepos} onClick={searchRepos}>
        List public repos:
      </button>
      {repoDetails} */}
      <RepoCard
        // repoDetails={repoDetails}
        // repoDetailsLoading={repoDetailsLoading}
        username={username}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchUser;

`
```

Comment: Skimming the code it looks legit, but when you use this component, do you correctly pass in the username as a prop `<RepoCard username={someUsername}/>`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I still get undefined

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try console logging `username` in the onChange handler of the form input. My guess is that your handler is not getting called, and hence username is not getting set. If this is the case, I would suggest binding to onKeydown. Either way, a few well placed breakpoints or console.log() calls should help you track down where this is not getting set or not getting passed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I tried a lot of console.log in different parts but the problem is, when I do this inside SearchUser component, it works perfectly. The problem is I want to create a component for repo, I don't want to do this inside SearchUser component. Because it makes it complex.

Comment: Well if I understand your code --and it's not easy to read with all of the commented out blocks-- the value is supposed to get set inSearchUser in the onChange event of the input. From there it gets passed as a prop to RepoCard. So I think either it is NOT getting set and you are passing undefined, OR RepoCard renders before you set the value and is not "listening" to the change. Can you tell us what happens if you console.log inside the onChange hander? I'd recommend deleting the commented out code, too. It will make it easier to see what's going on.